# Plotly Geographical mapping, set locationmode="IN"

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

Just like there is a 'USA-states' as locationmode in Geographical Plotting, is there something for India?

```
data = dict(type = 'choropleth',
        locations = ['AZ','CA','NY'],
        locationmode = 'USA-states',
        colorscale= 'Portland',
        text= ['text1','text2','text3'],
        z=[1.0,2.0,3.0],
        colorbar = {'title':'Colorbar Title'})
```

Comment: Did you look here? https://plot.ly/python/choropleth-maps/

Answer (score -2):

I was also searching soln for the same problem after doing some research I found that only one of the three listed parameter can be passed in locationmode which is 1.'ISO-3' (which by default) 2.'USA-states' 3.'country names'.however you can use layout = dict(geo={'scope':'asia'}) to view India map.Here is a link https://plot.ly/python/reference/#choropleth-locationmode